# How can I get reference to a variable by using a string, in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a variable `strFunction`, then I have another string `strName = "strFunction"` , what I want to know is how can I get the value of strFunction by using strName.

For example, something like getValue(strName) gives me the value of strFunction. Is it possible in Access VBA?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have a `strFunction` string, it's a const string.
In my code I want to use `Len("strFunction")` to test the length of it, but what i got is the length "strFunction". So I need a get-value-out-of-variable-name function. I have tried Eval(), but it cannot do this, even I write a `get_strFunction()`, `eval("get_strFunction()")` gives me error, telling me it cannot find it.

```
Private Const strFunction as String = "FilterByType_1"
Private Function get_strFunction()
    get_strFunction = strFunction
End Function
```

Comment: Works for me, if I change `Private Function` to `Public Function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*I have a variable strFunction, then I have another string strName = "strFunction" , what I want to know is how can I get the value of strFunction by using strName.*"

Instead of a variable, *strFunction* could be the key for an item in a VBA collection.

```
Public Sub darkjh()
    Dim strName As String
    Dim col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection
    col.Add "FilterByType_1", "strFunction"
    strName = "strFunction"
    Debug.Print col(strName)
    Set col = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit**:  Instead of a VBA collection, you could use a Scripting.Dictionary.

```
Dim strName As String
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "strFunction", "FilterByType_1"
strName = "strFunction"
Debug.Print dict(strName)
Set dict = Nothing
```

Comment: OH just like a dictionary in Python. I'll try it out tomorrow!

Comment: Yes.  I added a Scripting.Dictionary example, which you might prefer if you're a Python person.

Comment: These 2 methods also work in VB6 as a way to replace a variable-string name inside a string by the contents of that variable-string. (Note for VB6 users, as Mods deleted my VB6 specific question).

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database

Dim a As String
Dim b As String

Public Sub test()
    a = "b"
    b = "test-string"
    Debug.Print Eval("get" & a & "()")
End Sub

Public Function getB() As String
    getB = b
End Function
```

Output

```
>>test
test-string
```

`eval(a)` did not work, so I had to write a "getter" for the variable and eval that function: `eval("get" & a & "()")`.

Comment: eval function cannot get a value of a variable... eval("strFunction") gives me error.

Comment: @darkjh update the question with your code, so we can help you.

Comment: If you're using Eval(), you want `eval(strFunction)` instead of `eval("strFunction")` -- putting the quotes in forces Eval() to look at the literal string of the variable name, whereas leaving out the quotes causes Eval() to look at the string stored in the variable.