# reading the values of a run-time variables in a for loop

Tags: ms-access

In the following code below...
value of kk1 = "one", kk2 = "Two", kk3 = "Three" and kk4 = "Four".

I want the msgbox to display One, Two, Three and Four instead of KK1, KK2, KK3 and KK4

```
For i = 1 To 4
    vari_value = "kk" & i
    MsgBox vari_value
Next
```

Comment: Nowhere is specified that `kk1 = "one"`, etc. ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reference variable name in excel vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336006/reference-variable-name-in-excel-vba)

Comment: It's not possible. Use an Array instead.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/q/6646864/3820271

Comment: Cannot dynamically build variable names in VBA. You are simply concatenating literal string "kk" with index number and setting vari_value to this constructed string value. As @Andre says, an array will probably serve your needs.

Comment: Ok Great...Thanks @andre and all

Answer (score 1):

By using Select case statment that can be achieved, refer to the below code which loops from 1 to 4 with value "KK1", "KK2", "KK3","KK4"

```
Public Sub run()
For i = 1 To 4
vari_value = "kk" & i
Select Case vari_value
    Case Is = "kk1"
        MsgBox "One"
    Case Is = "kk2"
        MsgBox "Two"
    Case Is = "kk3"
        MsgBox "Three"
    Case Is = "kk4"
        MsgBox "Four"
End Select
'MsgBox vari_value
Next
End Sub
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Actually @Nishit, KK1, KK2, KK3 and KK4 are form Variables with the sample values - "One", "Two", "Three" & "Four"

I want the value of KK1, KK2, KK3 and KK4 to be displayed in the message box which is not a fixed value

Comment: how many variables you have, if that is codeable you can use this. If not then vba cannot dynamically build variable names in VBA. Could you please be more specific on what you need.

Comment: If you want to define KK1,KK2,KK3 as a dyanamic variable it cannot be done. For a simple reason that LHS or RHS or both  should be static to be used.
Let take your case, when the value of vari_value is KK1 = "One" in 1st intance, as soon as the value of "i" is incremented value of vari_value i.e KK1 is changed to KK2, so the KK1 is lost

Comment: Thanks a lot....I wanted to create and use dynamic variables to shorten my code. Seems not possible, hence I shall to write repeated "insert into" statements multiple times with the variable names being hard-coded for every insert into statement