# VBA: Is it possible to create an array of string variables?

Tags: vba

I am trying to create an array of string **variables** (not an array of text **strings**, so to speak), with the goal of passing each variable into the following procedure.

In my actual use case, I have two large blocks of code that are exactly the same for each of two string variables, and I am really just trying to shorten / consolidate my code.

I have pasted an example of the code below.

So I get it...the test will always print "Fail" because it's essentially testing if "strA" = "Apple" and then if "strB" = "Apple", but my intent is for it to test if strA = "Apple" and then if strB = "Apple" (where strA and strB are treated as variables).

Any advice? Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible? Thank you much.

```
Sub ArrayTest()

'Declare variables
Dim strA As String: strA = "Apple"
Dim strB As String: strB = "Banana"
Dim strArray() As String: strArray = Split("strA,strB", ",")
Dim i As Long
Dim strResult As String

'Test the array
For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)
    If strArray(i) = "Apple" Or strArray(i) = "Banana" Then
        strResult = "Pass"
    Else: strResult = "Fail"
    End If
    Debug.Print strResult
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary keyed by `"A", "B"` etc.? There is no direct way of doing what you want to do, but even if there were, it would probably be a bad decision. Seems like a classic case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835). What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @JohnColeman I have two large blocks of code that are *exactly* the same for each of two string variables (aside from the string variable referenced in each block, of course), and I'm really just trying to shorten / consolidate my code. As for your suggestion using a dictionary, I will research how to do so as I'm unfamiliar with this concept, and I appreciate your advice.

Comment: @Chase I was going to vote to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6646864/11683, now I'm wondering whether what you are asking about is how to pass a variable to a procedure.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for your feedback GSerg - I have edited my question for clarity (and you are correct, that is what I'm attempting to do).

Comment: @Chase So have `Sub ThatLargeBlockOfCode(byval s as string)` and call it `ThatLargeBlockOfCode "Apple"` and `ThatLargeBlockOfCode "Banana"`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong linking of variables and characters.

```
Sub ArrayTest()

'Declare variables
Dim strA As String: strA = "Apple"
Dim strB As String: strB = "Banana"
Dim strC As String
strC = strA & "," & strB
Dim strArray() As String: strArray = Split(strC, ",")
Dim i As Long
Dim strResult As String

'Test the array
For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)
    If strArray(i) = "Apple" Or strArray(i) = "Banana" Then
        strResult = "Pass"
    Else: strResult = "Fail"
    End If
    Debug.Print strResult
    Next

End Sub
```